# insert checkbox before link?

Tags: javascript, jquery

html

```
<ul class="navmore">
   <li><a href="link">Link</a></li>
   <li><a href="link">Link</a></li>
</ul>
```

jquery in footer

```
$(".navmore li a").each(function(){
   var $this = $(this);
   $('<input type="checkbox">').insertBefore($this);
});
```

html should become

```
    <ul>
       <li><input type="checkbox"><a href="link">Link</a>
       <li><input type="checkbox"><a href="link">Link</a>
    </ul>
```

I currently don't get any checkbox with that code

Comment: nope, sorry that was a typo. updated.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/SDyrg/ Works fine for me.

Comment: Did you remember document ready ?

Comment: @rob.m review your issue. http://jsbin.com/imiwiv/2/edit Your problem is more banal nature than we might think. Close the `<input />` tag and wrap all into a `ready` function: `$(function(){ /**/ });`

Comment: On which browser you experience this? Your code seems to be working. You don't need `.each` there BTW. `$('<input type="checkbox" />').insertBefore($('.navmore li a'));` will also work.

Comment: @roXon this is hillarious. It was .navMore and not .navmore. Big fail.

Comment: exactly! can't delete the question due to the answers now. :(

Comment: @hahaha unbelievable :) **** happens ;)

Answer (score 2):

No need for a loop ?

```
$(function() {
    $(".navmore li a").before( $('<input />', {type:"checkbox"}));
});
```

Comment: The OP code is fully working. http://jsbin.com/imiwiv/1/edit might be missing the closing input tag. +1 anyway

Comment: append? thougth insertBefore was ok?

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function () {
    $(".navmore li").prepend('<input type="checkbox" />');
});
```